# Thinking about What Others Think of You

Tags: metacognition, awareness

When a mind develops, it goes through numerous stages of awareness, such as (not necessarily in order)

- Awareness of others
- Awareness of self
- Awareness of other's thoughts (this may not be a discrete stage)

What do you call the awareness of other's awareness of you (and the logical deduction of what they believe you're thinking)?

I believe this should be the stage before meta-gaming is possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/23323/7001

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sort of thinking is called [theory of mind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_of_mind) (not to be confused with theories of how the mind works).

It's not entirely clear whether theory of mind is a discrete ability or a spectrum, but tasks requiring higher-order theorizing tend to be more difficult and are more likely to be lost to dysfunction:

> Cognitive theory of mind is further separated into first order (e.g., I think she thinks that…) and second order (e.g., he thinks that she thinks that…)

I'm not aware of a specific term that distinguishes second-order theory of mind when the second-order person is in fact the first-person rather than a third-person (e.g., "she thinks that I think that...").